# Backup files listed in tar archive before unpacking for simple rollback

Tags: linux, macos, tar, rollback

Before unpacking a compressed tar file, what is the best way to backup the files that will be overwritten?

For example, given the input archive `files.tar.gz` containing:

```
path/to/fileA.txt
path/to/fileB.txt
path/to/fileC.txt
```

and currently on the filesystem we have:

```
path/to/fileA.txt
path/to/fileC.txt
```

Since fileA.txt and fileC.txt will be overwritten, we would like to have `files-backup.tar.gz` which contains only those two original files.

Currently I'm doing this manually to have a crude rollback mechanism if things don't work out. With more than a handful of files in several locations this can become a pain.

Would love to script it up or learn a new hidden parameter for the tar command.

**UPDATE**: The best so far I've come up with is:

```
tar ztf files.tar.gz | xargs tar zcvf /tmp/file-backup.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you had is a good start, but one thing to be aware of is that xargs will process stdin lines in groups. (That's its whole purpose in life afterall: to take an unlimited number of input lines and execute a command multiple times, each time with a subset of input lines as command line arguments.)  When `files.tar.gz` has a huge number of files, xargs will do `tar zcvf /tmp/file-backup.tar.gz` on a subset of them at a time!  The resulting `/tmp/file-backup.tar.gz` will contain only the last subset of files!

I will assume that since you specified paths as `path/.../...` that all paths will be in relative.

Here's a better solution (see "notes" below on use of `tar ...|while read...`):

```
(tar ztf files.tar.gz|while read f; do if [ -f "$f" -o -h "$f" ]; then echo "$f" ; fi; done)|tar Tcfz - /tmp/`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`.file-backup.tar.gz
```

The `tar` command produces a file named `/tmp/yyyymmdd_hhmmss.file-backup.tar.gz` containing the list of files supplied on its stdin, which is the list of files and symbolic links in `files.tar.gz`.

Finally, you might want to consider a couple of alternatives that might make hosuekeeping easier:

1. Only save off files that have actually changed, instead of saving off every file.
2. Or, instead of saving off files into a tar/gzip file, rename files in place; this way, you'd see right away which files have newer version(s) without needing to go look into several different `/tmp/yyyymmdd_hhmmss.file-backup.tar.gz` files first:

```
(TAG=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'` ; tar ztf files.tar.gz|while read f; do if [ -f "$f" -o -h "$f" ]; then mv "$f" "$f.$TAG" ; fi; done)
```

NOTE: the `tar ztf ...|while read f` ensures that filenames containing whitespace(s) won't cause a problem.  The simpler

```
for f in `tar ztf files.tar.gz`; do...
```

won't work when there are files in `files.tar.gz` with whitespace(s) in their name.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer. I'll test it out. Yes, the paths are relative, the script will be run in the target directory. Did not know about xargs doing a subset at a time and that tar will only have the previous subset. I'd better upgrade my script pronto. Cheers.